# Div vs Div span to display text in user interface angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I creating a UI screen in angular to display fields like first name , last name etc
I am using span inside the div tag. My question is do I need to used span tag or is div enough.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div *ngIf="!EditMode"><span>{{ManagerDetails.Person.FIRST_NAME}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use span tag. Example:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerDetails.Person.FIRST_NAME}}</div>
    </div>
```

Better solution would be

```
    <div *ngIf="!EditMode" class="col-md-3">
        {{ManagerDetails.Person.FIRST_NAME}}
    </div>
```